# Where do I find a car in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

I've seen people driving cars in DayZ (not standalone) but everytime I find one it is all messed up. Do I need to buy them somewhere or where do I go to find non-broken cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're on a modded server, it's exceptionally rare to find a fully working vehicle. However, vehicles can be repaired to working order.

To determine what repairs are needed, you can either sit in the driver seat or, while standing next to the vehicle, use the mouse wheel to select the repair menu. In either case, you will see the status of each vehicle part indicated by color. A green part is fully repaired, an orange part is damaged and a red part is broken. Once a part is red, it is no longer functional.

A vehicle requires the following non-broken parts to be drivable:

- Engine (repaired with Engine Parts)
- Fuel Tank (repaired with Fuel Tank Parts)
- All Wheels (repaired with Wheels)
- Hull (repaired with Scrap Metal)

The repair parts can be found throughout the map, but are generally located in industrial buildings.

To repair a part you must have the part in your inventory and you must also have a toolkit. (If you've picked up a toolkit, it will be placed in one of the tools slots of your inventory, next to flashlights, matches, etc). You can select the part to repair from the repair menu, but you must be outside the car to do so.

A vehicle also requires gas. You can see the level of fuel when you're in the driver seat. If it's empty, you won't be able to start it. You will need to find a jerry can. Any jerry can found in the world will already be filled with gas. However, if you have an empty can on you, you will need to find a gas station to fill it. Then, you need to be standing next to the car and use the mouse wheel to select the refuel option.

One final word about repairing a vehicle. It can be time consuming because of the potential many trips required back and forth from the car to towns. You can hold only so many parts at a time. So, if the vehicle you found is completely broken, you're probably looking at more than several trips to bring parts to it.

Here's how many inventory slots each part takes up:

- Engine Parts = 6 slots
- Fuel Tank Parts = 4 slots
- One Wheel = 6 slots
- Scrap Metal = 3 slots
- Jerry Can = 3 slots
- Windscreen = 1 slots (this is not required for the vehicle to work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mouse over it and get in check what is broken and fix that (shows top left corner). Once you have repaired it check if it has fuel and if it does not get a jerrycan and refill it you can get more fuel from a fuel station then get in and use W (forward) S (back/brake) A (left) D (right).

[Source](http://forums.dayzgame.com/index.php?/topic/82940-how-do-you-driveanything/)

As to where they spawn, check out the [Wiki Page](http://dayz.gamepedia.com/Mod:Vehicles#Spawn_Locations_of_Vehicles)

NB Not a Day-Z player, so if this is incorrect, let me know and I'll delete it